# How to create DbModificationClause with CASE WHEN .... THEN

Tags: entity-framework-6

all

I was create IDbCommandTreeInterceptor and got the problem: EF provider wrong sql generation. As a result, I want to get this SQL

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Devices] SET [DeletedDate] = CASE 
WHEN [DeletedDate] IS NULL THEN GETUTCDATE()    
ELSE [DeletedDate] END
```

Code for testing. Interseptor class for fake delettion.

```
public class SoftDeleteInterseptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    private const string DELETED_DATE_COLUMN = "DeletedDate";        

    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace)
        {
            return;
        }            

        var deleteCommand = interceptionContext.OriginalResult as DbDeleteCommandTree;
        if (deleteCommand != null)
        {
            interceptionContext.Result = HandleDeleteCommand(deleteCommand);
            return;
        }
    }

    private DbCommandTree HandleDeleteCommand(DbDeleteCommandTree deleteCommand)
    {
        if (!IsPropertyExists(deleteCommand, DELETED_DATE_COLUMN))
        {
            return deleteCommand;
        }

        var deletedProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(
            DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType, deleteCommand.Target.VariableName),
            DELETED_DATE_COLUMN
        );

        var caseValue = DbExpressionBuilder.Case(
            new DbExpression[] { deletedProperty.IsNull() },
            new DbExpression[] { EdmFunctions.CurrentUtcDateTime() },
            deletedProperty);

        var setClauses = new List<DbModificationClause> { DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(deletedProperty, caseValue) };

        return new DbUpdateCommandTree(
            deleteCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
            deleteCommand.DataSpace,
            deleteCommand.Target,
            deleteCommand.Predicate,
            setClauses.AsReadOnly(), null);            
    }

    private bool IsPropertyExists(DbModificationCommandTree command, string property)
    {
        var table = (EntityType)command.Target.VariableType.EdmType;
        return table.Properties.Any(p => p.Name == property);
    }

}
```

Create configuration class for register DbInterseptor.

```
public class CustomDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public CustomDbConfiguration()
    {
        AddInterceptor(new SoftDeleteInterseptor());
    }
}
public partial class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    static IDCompleteDbContext()
    {
        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new CustomDbConfiguration());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CommandEntity> CommandEntities { get; set; }
}

public class CommandEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime? DeletedDate {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

When delete entity, entity did not deleted

```
var context = new CustomDbContext();
var entity = context.CommandEntities.First();
context.CommandEntities.Remove(entity);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Did not work. EF provider generate wrong SQL:     UPDATE [dbo].[Devices] SET [DeletedDate] = [DeletedDate] IS NULL@0[DeletedDate] WHERE ([Id] = @1) @0: '01.05.2018 7:45:22' (Type = DateTime2) @1: '20' (Type = Int32)

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more code in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added more code

Comment: Thank you, I was able to reproduce it. The good thing is that your code is fine. The bad thing is that, after looking at the EF source code, the SQL generator for Sql Server does not handle correctly `CASE` expressions in DML (insert, update, delete) commands. Most likely because EF itself does not generate such expressions. I see no workaround, sorry.